# std::cout printing forbidden system info to the console

Tags: c++, debugging, cout, buffer-overflow

I have a c++ program which runs continuously and in order to debug it I print some values to the console using cout. This has been working fine for the past week.

Now however, after about 30 seconds it will print information that it should not have access to, and stops printing what I tell it to completely.

Here is an example:

```
Object 104 dist: 0.111448
Object 104 dist: 0.113334
Object 104 dist: 0.0950752
JRE_HOME=/jreLS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;3^C
```

In the above example, I tell the program to print the "Object dist" on every iteration, then suddenly it spits out this JRE_HOME info that it should not have access to, then stops printing all together. Apart from the printing stopping, the program continues to run fine.

I am worried that I might have some kind of memory leak or buffer overflow, but I do not know how to diagnose this as I am fairly new to C++ and have no idea what might be causing this (I have looked through my recent code changes and nothing stands out as an obvious cause).

I have restarted my computer but each time it just prints out more random system info which it should not have access to which again leads me to believe it is reading from some part of system memory.

What could be causing this?

Comment: What about posting some code?

Comment: Well, it's almost certainly Undefined Behavior somewhere. So once he finds and isolates the offending code, it's a safe bet that the bugfix is also clear. The hard part is just finding that, and we don't have a crystal ball either.

Comment: Extra info which might help: 

1. This does not happen if I tell the program not to print anything at all to the console.

2. This is an OpenCV program, I don't if this might be a known bug within that library.


Also, this is a pretty big program and I don't know where this bug is coming from so I don't think posting a huge bunch of code would be of any use.

Comment: It's printing out part of the environment. Each process has their own copy of the environment, which they have full access to.

Comment: Looks like a buffer overflow (possibly in another part of your app than the output code). If you want more than guesses, you will have to post some code.

Answer (score 2):

> that it should not have access to

You are mistaken, each process has a copy of the environment block in its memory space.

You are seeing snippets of environment variables because you are using an invalid pointer, that happens to land within the environment block instead of the intended data.